# Unable to run Vagrant on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I just recently installed Vagrant and Virtualbox but am unable to run Vagrant. I'm getting the following error when I run 'vagrant up':

```
roosterlegs@roosterlegs-Lenovo-Y50-70:~/vagrant_proj$ vagrant up
VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

Then when I run 'VBoxManage --version', I get:

```
roosterlegs@roosterlegs-Lenovo-Y50-70:~/vagrant_proj$ VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.0.18_Ubuntur106667
```

I have tried a number of solutions such as the instructions here:
[How to correct virtualbox installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291015/how-to-correct-virtualbox-installation), but nothing has seemed to work.

Please help.

Comment: You sure you have `linux-headers-generic` and `virtualbox-ose-dkms` installed?

Comment: I believe I have `linux-headers-generic`, but when I try to install the other one, I get an error: `E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-ose-dkms`

Comment: But I did successfully install `virtualbox-dkms`

Comment: run `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers-generic` if package is not installed run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: I already have those installed. Still getting the same errors when I try to run `vagrant up`.

Comment: Did anyone solved this issue?

Comment: secure boot was the issue , I just disabled and then it starts to work

Answer (score 4):

For others who are also having the issue, disable the secure boot. Worked to me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling `virtualbox-dkms` (via `aptitude reinstall virtualbox-dkms`) did the trick for me. It forced the rebuild of the modules and whatnot, now my VMs boot again =)

Hope this helps